# Subtracting two dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe:

`hourly = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(24,2)), columns=['mean','std'])
hourly.index.name = 'Hour'`

And I would like to plot the Hourly mean,together with the standard deviation either side, and shade the area in between the standard deviation bands. I have the following code to do this:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(hourly["mean"].index, hourly["mean"] , 'k')
upp_bd = hourly["mean"].add(2*hourly['std'])
low_bd = hourly['mean'].subtract(2*hourly['std'])    
plt.fill_between(hourly.index, upp_bd,low_bd,color='b', alpha=0.2)
```

Unfortunately I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible
```

The `hourly["mean"]` variable has the following data structure:

```
      SomeNum
Hour           
0     50.003195
1     50.003687
2     50.005464
3     50.002127
4     49.998756
5     50.000194
6     49.994266
7     49.989631
8     49.997383
9     49.998948
10    50.005860
11    49.999882
12    50.000132
13    49.997024
14    49.995282
15    49.994489
16    49.995658
17    50.006386
18    50.004037
19    49.999172
20    49.999787
21    50.000317
22    50.000174
23    50.002752
```

The `upp_bd` and `low_bd` variables have this structure:

```
      SomeNum
Hour           
0     50.112504
1     50.108413
2     50.107596
3     50.104473
4     50.099938
5     50.108084
6     50.106991
7     50.102655
8     50.107372
9     50.106870
10    50.111932
11    50.105725
12    50.104598
13    50.101926
14    50.100037
15    50.103230
16    50.107482
17    50.115969
18    50.114712
19    50.112294
20    50.116430
21    50.116907
22    50.109491
23    50.110875
```

and the `hourly.index` variable has this structure:

```
Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
           dtype='int64', name=u'Hour')
```

Note, the first plot `plt.plot(hourly["mean"].index, hourly["mean"] , 'k')` works fine.

Comment: You're trying to plot hourly and daily?  Are those frames the same shape?  My guess is one is a different dimension than the other, so the plot library can't handle it.

Comment: `daily["mean"]` and `hourly["mean"]` have same dimensions?

Comment: Apologies - a typo. It's all hourly. Have corrected the question now. They should all have the same dimensions.

Comment: For which line do you get this exception? Also can you show the dimensions of each variable you are using (or even better, provide a reproducible example)

Comment: Good suggestion. I have done this. The code fails on the last line with the ``plt.fill_between`` function

Comment: Thanks for the reproducible example! But, that works for me. What versions of pandas and matplotlib are you using?

Comment: matplotlib==1.4.3 and pandas==0.16.2

Comment: The same here with no problem. Can you post the full error traceback?

Comment: The stack trace references different code version. There you're using hourly and daily. Do they have the same dimensions? Also, you're plotting `upp_bd.index` against `upp_bd` and the 4th arg translates to `where=upp_bd`. The code works for me with same lib versions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The errors happened because of my poor cut and paste between the real code an the "reproducible" code. The reproducible code does work for my now. The actual code doesn't :|

Comment: Can you post then the dimensions of the object in the actual code?

Comment: It's not a lot of value, but you can do `hourly["mean"].plot(c='k')` instead of `plt.plot(hourly["mean"].index, hourly["mean"] , 'k')`

Comment: your code works for me in 2.7 and gets what's you want.